# Vários Select Sum com parametros de tabelas relacionadas

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Tentei fazer uma consulta SubSelect quando um usuario quiser pesquisar o Patrimônio por Produto, por Localização e por Situação o Total da soma seja alterada. E ele só soma o Patrimônio em que Ativo = true. Segue o comando Sql que fiz. Por favor, peço ajuda.

```
SELECT USUARIO.[usu_codigo], Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0)) As Soma,  
    (SELECT Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0)) WHERE PATRIMONIO.[pat_codproduto] = PRODUTO.[prod_codigo] And ((PRODUTO.[prod_nome]) = ?)) As SomaProduto, 
    (SELECT Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0)) WHERE PATRIMONIO.[pat_codlocalizacao] = LOCALIZACAO.[loc_codigo] And ((LOCALIZACAO.[loc_nome]) = ?)) As SomaLocalizacao,  
    (SELECT Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0)) WHERE PATRIMONIO.[pat_codlocalizacao] = PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao] And ((PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao]) = ?)) As SomaSituacao  
FROM USUARIO, PATRIMONIO, PRODUTO, LOCALIZACAO 
GROUP BY USUARIO.[usu_codigo], PRODUTO.[prod_nome], LOCALIZACAO.[loc_nome], PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao] 
HAVING(((USUARIO.[usu_codigo]) = ?));
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou desse jeito, não sei como vai ficar em termo de performance. Alguém tem alguma sugestão para simplificar este select?

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT USUARIO.[usu_codigo], Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0))
FROM USUARIO LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO ON USUARIO.[usu_codigo] = PATRIMONIO.[pat_codusuario]
GROUP BY USUARIO.[usu_codigo] HAVING(((USUARIO.[usu_codigo]) = ?))
UNION ALL
SELECT PRODUTO.[prod_nome], Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0))
FROM PRODUTO LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO ON PRODUTO.[prod_codigo] = PATRIMONIO.[pat_codproduto]
GROUP BY PRODUTO.[prod_nome] HAVING(((PRODUTO.[prod_nome]) = ?))
UNION ALL
SELECT LOCALIZACAO.[loc_codigo], Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0))
FROM LOCALIZACAO LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO ON LOCALIZACAO.[loc_codigo] = PATRIMONIO.[pat_codlocalizacao]
GROUP BY LOCALIZACAO.[loc_codigo] HAVING(((LOCALIZACAO.[loc_codigo]) = ?))
UNION ALL
SELECT PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao], Sum(IIF(PATRIMONIO.[pat_ativo] = true, (PATRIMONIO.[pat_valortotal]), 0))
FROM PATRIMONIO
GROUP BY PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao] HAVING(((PATRIMONIO.[pat_situacao]) = ?)));